# Silverlight 4 Wizard Control

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, wizard

I am about to create a Wizard control that I am hoping to make as reusable as possible in Silverlight 4.  Does anyone know of any existing controls, I have found a few examples but they are Silverlight 2, I have read some information on people suggesting to use the navigation framework but correct me if I am wrong doesn't this work of the current Url as opposed to being an easy way to swap out user controls in a Wizard scenario?

Any insight on the best approach/existing examples would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this

http://weblogs.asp.net/bryansampica/archive/2010/07/21/silverlight-4-0-wizard-custom-control.aspx